# Ratio Test help

Tags: real-analysis

Ok this is a little exercise I am trying to do that branches off the ratio test.

Prove the following statement: Let a(n) be a sequence. If lim |a(n+1)/a(n)| = r exists then show 
i) the series a(n) converges if r<1 and

ii) the series a(n) diverges if r>1.

Im a little lost on where to start with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty standard result that can be found in any math analysis textbook!

Answer (score 1):

For the case where $r<1$, we can choose a number $m$ such that $r<m<1$. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}\right|=r<m.
$$
Thus for some $N>0$, this gives us $|a(n+1)|<m|a(n)|$ when $n\geq N$. In general, we get that
$$
|a(N+k)|<m^{k}|(a(N)|
$$
which gives us the geometric series 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a(N)|m^{k}
$$
which converges (why?) and hence by the comparison test, the series
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|a(n)|
$$ 
converges. Note that I have left out details that you are supposed to fill in.

For the case r>1, we again have an integer $N>0$ such that 
$$
\left|\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}\right|>1
$$
when $n\geq N$ and hence 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}\not=0.
$$
Applying the divergence test gives us the result that we want. Fill in the details.

As kermani has noted in the comments above, this proof can be found in any standard analysis textbook.

Comment: The OP's claim IS the ratio test. This is exactly the statement that the OP wants to prove.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for letting me know. OP said he was branching off of the ratio test so I thought he already had the ratio test which was strange...